# Как эффективно вычислить новых/ушедших пользователей группы Вконтакте

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, vkontakte-api, ruby

Мне необходимо иметь актуальные данные по новым и ушедшим пользователями из группы Вк. Работать буду с большим количеством групп.

Изначально я получаю id всех участников группы Вк и сохраняю в их БД отдельными записями в таблицу `group_members` c полями `group_id`, `user_id`.

Периодически я заново опрашиваю Вк, чтобы обновить информацию о пользователях. Проверять все id по одному - неэффективно. Я думаю о том, что можно сравнивать массив id с тем, что есть в БД, чтобы сначала найти тех, кого в БД нет (новые), а потом тех, кого нет в ответе ВК (ушедшие). Как лучше это сделать?

Т.к. люди постоянно приходят/уходят, то в массивах будут большие отклонения. Нужно ли их где-то хранить, если, например, имеем дело с группой с 10млн участников? Redis?

Как наиболее эффективно все это сделать?

Использую PostgreSQL, Ruby on Rails.

**UPDATE**
У Вк есть метод `execute`, так что можно получать 25000 участников за раз. `Сallback API`, к сожалению, подключается только к моим сообществом, а я хочу мониторить конкурентов. Я понимаю, что надо будет купить IP для быстроты.

Comment: Очень сумбурно описано. Какие данные между "осмотрами" вы хотите получить в результате? Количество пришедших/ушедших? Состав? Что из этого вы хотите хранить и в течение какого времени?

Answer (score 0):

В group_members хранить подробную информацию по двум последним сборам, например, за вчера и сегодня. А итоговую - можно и долго, она много места не займёт.

В БД это может выглядеть примерно так:
Таблица **group_members** (id_вставки, group_id , user_id , дата , ....);
    где id_вставки - одинаковый для каждого сбора информации.
Таблица **history** (group_id , дата, было, стало, пришло, ушло ...)

В group_members храним данные с двух сборов информации, предыдущий и текущий.
После вставки данных очередного сбора делаем выборки:

```
1) -- сколько было в каждой группе
   select group_id, count(*) 
     from group_members 
    where id_вставки = ПРЕДЫДУЩИЙ
    group by group_id 

2) -- сколько стало
   select group_id, count(*) 
     from group_members 
    where id_вставки = ТЕКУЩИЙ
    group by group_id 

3) -- сколько покинуло
    select group_id, count (*) from (
            select group_id , user_id  
              from group_members 
             where id_вставки = ПРЕДЫДУЩИЙ
             group by group_id 
              EXCEPT       
            select group_id , user_id
              from group_members 
             where id_вставки = ТЕКУЩИЙ
             group by group_id 
    )

4) -- сколько новых - то же самое, что и п.3 - 
      только поменять местами ПРЕДЫДУЩИЙ и ТЕКУЩИЙ
```

Результаты всех этих запросов помещаем в таблицу history.

И затем удаляем из group_members:

```
delete from group_members  
 where id_вставки = ПРЕДЫДУЩИЙ
```

Если этап delete долгий - можно посмотреть в сторону пары таблиц и truncate, или секционирования и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне нужно знать не количество, а id этих людей. Я думаю, что лучше создавать временную таблицу для нового запроса, а потом все изменения записывать в основную. Но вот как лучше сравнивать 2 таблицы, чтобы получить id? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428966/postgresql-how-to-get-entries-in-a-table-that-do-not-have-a-match-in-another-t вот такой вариант наилучший?

Comment: @leemour а вы постройте планы для решений с `EXCEPT`, `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` и, для полноты, с `NOT EXISTS`. Возможно, постгрес их примется выполнять одинаковым образом. А если нет, у вас будут цифры.

Comment: Приведите пример входных и выходных данных